# Function that reads a file that's opened in another function is producing error

Tags: python, function, file

There's more to the program than this, but for now this is the trouble I'm having; I want 2 different functions, open_file() that opens up a .txt file, and then a main() that controls everything (there are other functions besides the open_file for it to control) but I can't get the main() to even open and print the lines in the file.

```
def open_file():
    '''prompt for file name, open file, return file pointer'''
    filename = input("Input a file name: ")
    file=open(filename,'r')
    return file

def main():
    ## open the file
    open_file()
    file.readline()
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        #and then do other stuff with it
main()
```

When I run main(), it prompts for a file name, but when I enter it, it tells me that "name 'file' is not defined." How do I correct this?

Comment: You need to learn about variable scope. Generally, you should be passing arguments to a function, and returning data that you want to use outside that function. Alternatively, you can use the global scope, but that is not typically recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the return value of `open_file()` to a variable within `main()`:

```
def main():
    ## open the file
    file = open_file()
    ## ...
```

Comment: `file` is a reserved word in Python.

Comment: What is your claim based on, James?

Comment: @James it was in Python 2, not in Python 3. And it wasn't a reserved word, really, but it was the name of a built-in function (which one should avoid shadowing).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with` to open the file, and close it automatically when leaving the `with` block.  Like this:

Python3:

```
def main():
    filename = input("Input a file name: ")
    # Open the file, process it, and close it after processing.
    with open(filename) as f:
        process_file(f)

def process_file(fp_in):
    for line in fp_in:
        print(line, end="")
        #and then do other stuff with it

main()
```

Python2:

```
def main():
    filename = raw_input("Input a file name: ")
    # Open the file, process it, and close it after processing.
    with open(filename) as f:
        process_file(f)

def process_file(fp_in):
    for line in fp_in:
        print line,
        #and then do other stuff with it

main()
```